# How to use the fmt command with non-latin characters?

Tags: text-formatting

I need to use fmt to format some text output in Greek, but it does not behave as it does with latin characters. Consider for example the sentences with 15 characters below.

With latin characters:

```
 $echo "Have a nice day" | fmt -w 16
 Have a nice day
```

but, strangely, with non-latin characters:

```
 $echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | fmt -w 16
 Ηαωε α
 νιψε δαυ
```

In fact for the above string, the smallest value that it prints the sentence without line breaks would be `-w 28`:

```
 $echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | fmt -w 28
 Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ
 $echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | fmt -w 27
 Ηαωε α νιψε
 δαυ
```

Can somebody explain why this happens and how to fix it, if possible?

Comment: fmt -w 120 on ascii text give me similar results to fmt -w 205-220 on unicode text. So just double the amount of characters (depends on the encoding) to get acceptable results ;) The coreutils people were doing some work on multibyte chars last year, perhaps we'll see results of that soon. http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2016-07/msg00013.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, it is not working because Greek characters are non-Latin, Unicode characters, and:

> Unlike [par](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_(command)), fmt has no Unicode support, ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fmt

### Additional notes

The second part of your question on how-to, unfortunately,

Although there seems be a fairly recent technical report regarding how to wrap Unicode, for example Heninger, Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm , 2015-06-01 http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/ however this seems to be specification only, no actual implementation or mention of software how-to examples. You could try asking the author via the email listed.

Since the Wikipedia article on `fmt` referred to `par`, and it was available via `apt-get`, I decided to try it on your posted text.

But I was unsuccessful, it still doesn't wrap the way you wish:

```
$ echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | par 16gr
Ηαωε α
νιψε δαυ
```

The `man` page was difficult enough that even the author cautioned that it was: `not well-written for the end-user`, but if you are determined you could try your luck reading it.

Answer (score 4):

`fmt`, as such, generally does not support "non-latin" (in your example, probably UTF-8).  You could perhaps use `par`, which does do this.

Interestingly, the Solaris and FreeBSD manual pages for `fmt` are very similar, hinting that the program has been unimproved noticeably since the mid-1980s:

- [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/fmt-1.html#scrolltoc)
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fmt&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&arch=default&format=html)

`par` may be available as a package for your system.  If not, it is easy to compile, and found here:

http://www.nicemice.net/par/

On the other hand, *proper* support for UTF-8 in `par` has been lacking:

- [Re: Add UTF-8 support to textproc/par](https://www.mail-archive.com/ports@openbsd.org/msg61480.html) illustrates problems in incorporating improvements of this sort.
- [Debian Bug report logs - #310495
  par: Does not handle UTF-8 multibyte characters properly](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=310495) has been open a while

Answer (score 0):

[Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs)'s utils are usually UTF-8 aware. You can get them on your unix machine by installing [`plan9port`](https://github.com/9fans/plan9port). On macOS you can use Homebrew

`brew install plan9port`

which installs [their `fmt`](https://9fans.github.io/plan9port/man/man1/fmt.html) under the `9` command. It seems to behave the way you wanted:

```
$ echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | 9 fmt -w 16
Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ
$ echo "Ηαωε α νιψε δαυ" | 9 fmt -w 14
Ηαωε α νιψε
δαυ
```